# Calling MySQL function from within a SELECT statement takes significantly more time than calling the function alone from command prompt

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following function in mysql

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_project_uuid`(project_kee varchar(400)) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    declare v_project_uuid varchar(50);
    select project_uuid into v_project_uuid from projects where scope='PRJ' and kee=project_kee;
RETURN v_project_uuid;
END
```

When I run this function directly from the mysql command prompt, it runs in few milliseconds but when I use this function inside another select statements, executing that hosing select statement takes about 2-3 minutes.

```
select * from issues where project_uuid = get_project_uuid('Project1')
```

However when I take the select statement from the function and use it directly in the hosting select statement rather than the function call, it works in few milliseconds.

```
select * from issues where project_uuid = (
    select project_uuid from projects
    where scope='PRJ' and kee='Project1'
)
```

It seems quite unusual that using the function takes so much longer. Now I am forced not to use the function because of longer time. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Do you want to write a dummy function that just returns a hard-coded value instead of doing select? That would tell you if there is something wrong in the configuration of procedures themselves.

Comment: Try to add the keyword `DETERMINISTIC` before `BEGIN`. It will tell mysql to only calculate it once.

Comment: @blackpen: I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly. I supply a human readable data i.e. project name and in return i get a long unreadable unique key indicating the same project. Importantly this unreadable unique key is used as foreign key in other tables thus it is convenient to write a function to get this unique key (uuid in this case) by supplying the readable project name.

Comment: @Solarflare: The value of the function can vary in the execution of different sql commands however within a single sql command, the value remains the same. I did not know about deterministic. Thanks for the pointer, I will check it.

Comment: @brunns, Ok. I see. You have already tried it from outside, on command line and proved that the procedure works quiet fast on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the get_project_uuid() function from the command line, it only called once thus it runs faster.

When you use this function inside a select statement (i.e., 2nd code section from your question), depending on your statement, this function might be called for each row of the **issue** table used in the outer select statement. Now if **issue** table has a lot of rows, it might take longer time to execute.

Finally, in case of the 3rd code block, it can be faster, because mysql would not run the inner select statement for every row of the issue table. This is done as part of optimization by using the same value from the inner select statement.

If you want to use the function and still want it faster you can declare the function as **deterministic**. A function that always generates the same output given the same input can be declared as deterministic. Now you have to decide whether this hold in your case or not. Mysql would not complain if you wrongly declare an nondeterministic function as deterministic. But it is you who would get wrong result by doing so.